# python, stuck in infinite loop program

Tags: python

I am writing this python program and everything works but when I run it, I get stuck in an infinite loop. How do I fix it? thanks.

```
import sys
def main():
    name = input("Enter your name:")
    ssn = input("Enter your Social Security Number:")
    income = eval(input("Enter your net income:"))

    while income <= 0:
        print("Error, then net income you entered is less than zero! Try again.")
        income = eval(input("Enter your net income again:"))

    while income > 0:
        net = calc(income, name, ssn)

def calc(income, name, ssn):
    if income > 15000.00:
        tax = .05 * (income - 15000.00)
        print(tax)
        print(name)
        print(ssn)
        sys.exit
    elif income > 30000.00:
        tax = .1 * (income - 30000.00)
        print(tax)
        print(name)
        print(ssn)
        sys.exit
    else:
        print("There is no tax to be paid, income is in the first $15000.00")
        print(name)
        print(ssn)
        sys.exit
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

`sys.exit` is a function. You need to call it (`sys.exit()`) to exit the script.

Comment: thanks I figured it out I used break in the while income > 0 statement.

Comment: BTW, why do you need a loop there anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The second while in your main() is not needed.
The next thing is that "sys.exit" is not right, you have to write "sys.exit()".
In your calc() function you should replace if "if income > 15000.00:" with "if income > 15000.00 and income <= 30000:" or the elif case will never get considered.

Here the correct code:

```
import sys

def main():
    name = input("Enter your name:")
    ssn = input("Enter your Social Security Number:")
    income = eval(input("Enter your net income:"))
    while income <= 0:
        print("Error, then net income you entered is less than zero! Try again.")
        income = eval(input("Enter your net income again:"))
    net = calc(income, name, ssn)

def calc(income, name, ssn):
    if income > 15000.00 and income <= 30000:
        tax = .05 * (income - 15000.00)
        print(tax)
        print(name)
        print(ssn)
        sys.exit()
    elif income > 30000.00:
        tax = .1 * (income - 30000.00)
        print(tax)
        print(name)
        print(ssn)
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("There is no tax to be paid, income is in the first $15000.00")
        print(name)
        print(ssn)
        sys.exit()
main()
```